# How to blink LED using NodeMCU in Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino, led, esp8266, nodemcu, pir

I have alredy installed ESP8266 package in my Arduino library. I connected d0 pin of NodeMCU to LED's positive terminal and ground pin of nodeMCU to LED's
Negative terminal as well as I uploaded blink code which is included in the library, well code also had run well without any error even nodeMCU's LED also blinked well within the delay time but the LED that I have connected to nodeMCU, was not blinking. what was the problem on there

When I had made a motion detector project using NodeMCU, the same problem that I had met. I have got notification through blynk which was only motion detector connected and got offline. I couldn't get PIR's reading notification
but the sensor worked well when I connected into Arduino

Comment: Please clean up the question.

Comment: Which voltage are your pin output ? What is the LED forward voltage ? You need a resistor in series with the LED to control the LED's  current.

Comment: Did you configure the "blink" sketch to blink your own LED on pin D0 instead of the built-in LED? It's not advisable to connect an LED directly between an output pin and Ground. You should put a resistor (try 330 Ohm) between the output pin and the LED's positive terminal to protect your ESP8266 and your LED.